# SpringBoot start Failed , Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified

Tags: spring-boot

My spring-boot project do not need datasource config , but when I run it,I got the error:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active)

And there is nothing in my application.properties

And I have try to defind the Application by

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

but it do not work .

This is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.abtnetworks</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <pcap4j.version>1.7.3</pcap4j.version>
        <totems-topology.version>1.8.5-SNAPSHOT</totems-topology.version>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pcap4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pcap4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${pcap4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pcap4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pcap4j-packetfactory-static</artifactId>
            <version>${pcap4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pcap4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pcap4j-packetfactory-propertiesbased</artifactId>
            <version>${pcap4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <!--打包jar-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!--不打包资源文件-->
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>*.**</exclude>
                        <exclude>mybatis/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>sql/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>static/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>templates/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <!--MANIFEST.MF 中 Class-Path 加入前缀-->
                            <classpathPrefix>../lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <!--jar包不包含唯一版本标识-->
                            <useUniqueVersions>false</useUniqueVersions>
                            <!--指定入口类-->
                            <mainClass>com.abtnetworks.elksoc.log4p.TotemsSocLog4pApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <!--MANIFEST.MF 中 Class-Path 加入资源文件目录-->
                            <Class-Path>./resources/</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--拷贝资源文件 copy-resources-->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/resources</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--指定lib文件夹-Dloader.path=，去除lib的jar运行的jar包配置-->
                <configuration>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                    <includes>
                        <include>
                            <groupId>nothing</groupId>
                            <artifactId>nothing</artifactId>
                        </include>
                    </includes>
                    <!--使用外部配置文件，jar包里没有资源文件-->
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove anything related to database such as `jpa`, `jdbc`, `mysql`,.. in your `build.gradle`

Comment: ``` <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>```

Comment: this is all the dependencies , It seems do not contain datasource JAR ?

Comment: edit your question and add the maven/gradle dependency details properly